# Rapidjson parser does not recognize € or korean chars in utf8 encoded files

Tags: json, parsing, encoding, special-characters, rapidjson

I try to read a utf8 encoded json file with a special character € and various korean characters.

file content:
{"test":"this is german ä ü ö and € and this is korean 가 나 다"}

```
code:
std::ifstream ifs("utf8.txt");
rapidjson::IStreamWrapper isw( ifs );
rapidjson::Document doc;
doc.ParseStream( isw );
const char* cc = doc["test"].GetString();
const rapidjson::Value& test = doc["test"];
std::string s = test.GetString();
```

if i inspect cc,test or s, neither in cc nor in test nor in s the characters are not displayed       correctly. The document has no parser errors.
What am i doing wrong?
Compiler is Visual Studio 2019, iso c++ 14 standard. Target is a windows or console app, that doesn't matter.

```
expected:
cc=this is german ä ü ö and € and this is korean 가 나 다
test = this is german ä ü ö and € and this is korean 가 나 다
s=this is german ä ü ö and € and this is korean 가 나 다
```

result:
this is german ├ñ ├╝ ├Â and Ôé¼ and this is korean Û░Ç Ùéÿ Ùïñ

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'german ä ü ö and €; korean 가 나 다'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp850')` results to `german ├ñ ├╝ ├Â and Ôé¼; korean Û░Ç Ùéÿ Ùïñ`…